# React Navigation - Rerender a component after closing drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

There is some way to rerender a component after closing the drawer navigation (from 
[React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html) library)? Like an event or something like that?

Let me explain my problem: I'm not using a drawer navigation only for navigation purposes but also for settings in my app. For that reason, I want to change, for exemple, the language in my app and rerender the component behind the drawer (check the image). How can I achieve this?

Hope you can help me, thank you!

[image]

Comment: This seems perfect for your use case: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: Why don't you rerender on selecting the language? One more choice is, I had "this.props.navigation.state.isDrawerOpen" inside my DrawerComponent to change the status bar color. Check whether you can access this.

Comment: I rerender on selecting a language, but is the drawer component. What I want is when I close the drawer the component that is open behind needs to rerender too.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I didn't knew about that, so thank you. But unfortunately that will not help me, because I need to know when the drawer close and I think there is not a event for that... :/

Answer (score 0):

1) - Connect drawer to redux

2) - Dispatch and event when a setting is changed.

3) - Connect the component that needs re-rendering to redux settings state.
If the state is changed the component will automatically be re-rendered.

If you are not using redux you could try MobX or other alternatives:

https://medium.com/@machnicki/why-redux-is-not-so-easy-some-alternatives-24816d5ad22d

Without a proper state management what you want to achieve would probably add many ugly workarounds in the code.

Comment: Hi Florin! First of all, thnak you for your suggestion. But if I'm not using redux? xD

Comment: I would suggest you start using redux, it will save you a lot of time in the future. No idea what workarounds you would have to do to handle that without proper state management.

Answer (score 0):

I have done what you want to do with Redux, and I think that it is a good idea to use it.

Having said that, here is some code to know when the drawer is closed:

```js
const defaultGetStateForAction = DrawerStack.router.getStateForAction;
DrawerStack.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "Navigation/DRAWER_CLOSED":
      // Drawer is closing code goes here...
      break;
  }

  return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```